# Why is parsing a single item String into a JSONArray failing

Tags: java, android, json, django-rest-framework, arrays

I was wondering why my parsing code is not working. I am trying to get responses from a webserver (`GET`) request into a `JASONArray`. This is already working for multiple items (using `GET http://10.0.2.2:8000/exercises`). But if I try to receive a single item (`GET http://10.0.2.2:8000/exercises/1`) it fails. I already found the cause of the problem. `respJSON = new JSONArray(resp);` seems to fail on a String that is not surounded by `[` and `]`, as you can see from my sample output. 
Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here? Should I use a different method, specifically designed for simgle item requests to handle this? I could use a simple check for the first character in the string, but that is such a hack, that I cant believe this is the best way todo it.

(I am only posting the very minimal code of what I use + the output)

```
HttpHost target = new HttpHost(host, port, "http");
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(requestPath);
getRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
getRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
response = httpClient.execute(target, getRequest);

entity = response.getEntity();
String resp = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
return new JSONArray(resp);
```

Using this code on a request like `http://10.0.2.2:8000/exercises` produces the following output String, which can be parsed into a `JSONArray` (leaving the actual data in here, for better comparsion):

```
[{"name": "Ringe", "duration": "20", "repeats": "no repeats", "creationtime": "2014-06-07 19:24:53.206000", "pausetime": "3", "alarmsound": "default", "description": "this is android description", "type": "repeats"}, {"name": "fingerkraft", "duration": "-1", "repeats": "10", "creationtime": "2014-06-07 18:08:03.576000", "pausetime": "20", "alarmsound": "default", "description": "asdasdasd", "type": "repeats"}, {"name": "ringe", "duration": "12", "repeats": "no", "creationtime": "2014-06-07 00:54:22.844000", "pausetime": "23", "alarmsound": "default", "description": "asdasdasd", "type": "duration"}]
```

However, using this method on `http://10.0.2.2:8000/exercises/1` produces a String like

```
{"name": "ringe", "duration": "12", "repeats": "no", "creationtime": "2014-06-07 00:54:22.844000", "pausetime": "23", "alarmsound": "default", "description": "asdasdasd", "type": "duration"}
```

which can't be parsed into a `JSONArray` (return is null). So, is this the expected behaviour? I built the API (which is obviously rest) with the django-rest-framework.

Comment: Yes I do know what they are used for. The code is okay, as on the backend side it is django-rest-framework code, without any blackmagic involved (at least not from my side). I marked akperkins as correct, the server is correctly returning a single element. I have to use the "single" version to parse the object. So you could say, the code on my side was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String jsonStr = getJson();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

To create a single Json object.

Comment: I see your point. But as the rest API return types are generated by the django-rest-framework (from which I guess they thought about this), and they are using django's own methods, I guess the design approach is alright? I rather think, that I sould use two different methods, to get either a list of items (even if there is only ONE item in that list it will be an array) and a second method to get item-details, which will return an object (which I can still parse into an array if I want to). This way both methods do exactly what they are supposed todo and they are better to test.

Comment: @Squonk I think you are wrong. His "/excercises" should return an array of objects because that's what it is. In the same token "/excercises/ID" is returning a single object determined by a unique I'd value. For the web server to always return an array of one object, when the Api dictates there will always only be one object, is a bad Api design choice.